# How to get an SPI Analog-to-Digital (MCP3204) working with the GPIO?

Tags: gpio, python, sensor, analog-to-digital, spi

I have an MCP3204 12-bit Analog-to-Digital Converter (ADC), and a Raspberrypi.
 Does anyone know what I need to plug where to get them to communicate?
Is there an SPI python library I can use?
O am looking to use the onboard GPIO spi which is faster than bit-bangging.

[Schematic of MCP3204](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21298c.pdf)

Pin Diagram of The PI:
[image: Pin Diagram of The PI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, It seems like I found a way.

First, make sure the spi module is enabled.
In the file `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf` comment out the line:

```
#blacklist spi-bcm2708
```

There is a project called [webiopi](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/). The project has a python lib that supports a couple ADCs. The supported ADCs are [listed in this page](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/wiki/MCP3000) and include the MCP3204.
To install just the python library I used:

```
wget https://webiopi.googlecode.com/files/WebIOPi-0.6.0.tar.gz
tar xzvf WebIOPi-0.6.0.tar.gz
cd WebIOPi-0.6.0/python
sudo python setup.py install
```

(though I used a virtualenv).

Then I could pull data from the PI using this script, **run as SUDO**:

```
from webiopi.devices.analog import MCP3004, MCP3008, MCP3204, MCP3208

# Setup a MCP3204 on SPI CE0
mcp0 = MCP3204()
print mcp0.analogReadAllVolt()
```

The wiring is as follows (from ADC to Pi):

1. Vcc and Vref to +3.3
2. Analog Ground to Ground
3. SCLK to SP10 SCLK
4. CS/SHDN to SP10 CE0 N
5. CH0 to some resistor (or what you want to measure)
6. Digital ground to ground
7. Din to SPI MOSI
8. Dout to SPI MISO

Here is a diagram showing a similar connection I made once to an an AVR to show the pinout of the MCP3204:

[image: the pinout of the MCP3204 connected to an AVR, connections are similar]

Would love to hear your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try WiringPi2-Python from here: https://github.com/Gadgetoid/WiringPi2-Python

You will need to download and build WiringPi first:

```
git clone git://git.drogon.net/wiringPi && cd wiringPi && sudo ./build
```

Then try something like this:

```
import wiringpi2 as wpi
wpi.wiringPiSetup()
wpi.mcp3002Setup(70,SPI_CHANNEL)
value = wpi.analogRead(70)
```

Comment: I saw plenty of articles about the mcp3002, just to make sure - the interface to them is Identical? because they have different bit sizes (12bit vs 10bit).

Comment: Ok, got WiringPi2-Python, but it does not work. The [source shows its specific to mcp3002](https://github.com/Gadgetoid/WiringPi2-Python/blob/master/WiringPi/wiringPi/mcp23008.c). Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble to get it working after Python install. It turned out that the SPI module was not loaded. Check if you have it loaded by `lsmod` and look (or `grep`) for `SPI`

If it is not there try to go into the boot config to set things up

- I would do `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`
- run `sudo raspi-config`
- Select the option to enable SPI. Depending on which version you have it may be in different places in the menu.

I also enabled it to be loaded to kernel at boot. After a reboot it should work.

To find if it works, run `lsmod | grep SPI` - if you see a SPI in the output it works.